# Como testar um evento no teclado (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)

Tags: android, testes-funcionais

Estou realizando testes automáticos e gostaria de saber como pegar o e evendo IME_ACTION_DONE do teclado.

Segue o código:

```
@Test
public void shouldSearchUserOnMap(){
    SystemClock.sleep(2500);
    Login();
    onView(withId(R.id.searchButton)).perform(typeText("teste@gmail.com"));
    SystemClock.sleep(2500);
    onView(pressKey(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)).perform(click());

}
```

Agradeço a colaboração!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para resolver o `DONE` do teclado para testes Unitários/Interface, faça o seguinte: No código há o `editActionListener` com a ação do teclado desejada. Inclua então no teste:

```
onView(withId(R.id.seuedittext)).perform(pressImeActionButton());
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa do **OnEditorActionListener**

Exemplo:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);

et.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)  {

            //faz algo aqui

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Não funciona para teste de intaface